# jQuery hover issue on second function (mouseout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having an issue with .hover() on mouse'ing out. Doesn't seem to work. It works on the fade in, but not out. I am basically fading in another image on top of it. The 'clone' has a lower z-index to start, and I bring it forward and then fade it in on hover. Both images are stacked.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6AfM/

The JavaScript:

```
$.fn.hoverImage = function() {
    //add event handler for each image (otherwise it will add the same event handler for all images all at once)
    this.each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var magnifyImage = img.next();

        //hover: first function is for mouseover, second is on mouseout
        img.hover(function() {
            magnifyImage.css("z-index", 2).animate({
                opacity:0.8         
            }, 200);
        }, function() {
            magnifyImage.css("z-index", -200).animate({
                       opacity:0
                    }, 200);
        });
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```
<span class="img-span">                                
    <img src="(url)" class="project-img">                                                                    
    <img src="(url)" class="project-img-clone">                                                                    
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</span>
```

The CSS:

```
.img-span {
    width:27.08333333333333%; /* 260 / 960 */
    margin-right:3.009259259259259%; /* 26 / 864 */
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    position:relative;
}

.project-img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.project-img-clone {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index:-200;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle with the problem ?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/C6AfM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is since the clone is appearing the mouseleave is not firing in the original image, it is fired by the clone

```
$.fn.hoverImage = function() {
    //add event handler for each image (otherwise it will add the same event handler for all images all at once)
    this.each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var magnifyImage = img.next();
        console.log(magnifyImage);

        //hover: first function is for mouseover, second is on mouseout
        img.add(magnifyImage).hover(function() {
            magnifyImage.css("z-index", 2).animate({
                opacity:0.8         
            }, 200);
        }, function() {
            magnifyImage.css('opacity', 0);
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/utv8S/)

---

Or use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) - IE9+

```
.project-img-clone {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index:-200;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7kgXF/)

Comment: Thanks Arun! Definitely works now. Question, so when it goes on mouse out, isn't hover() still attached to the original image? Having trouble understanding how add() changes the dynamics of the event handler.

Comment: I think I am correct in saying that `.add(magnifyImage)` just means the `.hover()` event handler will be attached to *both* `img` and `magnifyImage`. However, because of the way one image hides the other when the z-index changes, only one of the two functions will fire for each image. So, the `mouseover` function will only ever fire on the original `img` and the `mouseout` function will only ever fire on the `magnifyImage`.

Comment: @Thomas - try changing the size of the `magnifyImage` in the CSS to, say, 80%. This will prevent `magnifyImage` from hiding `img` and allow the `mouseout` event handler to fire. You will then see what is happening.